# How can I convert an Italian residence study permit to a German residence permit if married to a non-eu BlueCard holder?

Tags: germany, blue-card

How can  I convert an Italian residence study permit to a German residence permit if married to a non-eu BlueCard holder(or a Niederlassungserlaubnis holder). I am an Indian citizen living in Italy on s student visa and my wife is an Indian citizen living in Germany. Do I need to first apply for a family reunion visa and the visit the residence permit office in Germany once I have been issued the German visa or I could just travel to Germany on my italian residence permit and ask for a residence card? Could someone perhaps point me to the right resource on the web. I would be grateful.

Comment: Normally as an Indian citizen you need to apply for a visa from the German embassy in India.  As you have a unique situation, I would suggest reaching out to the German embassy in Rome and ask them.  I suspect you will not be allowed to apply within Germany.

Comment: Hmm, I already did that but didn’t get a response , perhaps because the embassy officials are very busy . Thank you very much for trying to help . :)